# Why is ActiveMQ consumer seen as connected for 10 seconds after killing it?

Tags: activemq-classic

I'm getting started and I've encountered some problem with ActiveMQ. I'm using local ActiveMQ without any customizations, I've written simple publisher app

```java
@Component
public class VirtualTopicSender {

    @Autowired
    private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

    public void send() {
        Topic topic = new ActiveMQTopic("VirtualTopic.TEST-VIRTUAL-TOPIC");
        int i = 0;

        while(true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(topic, i++);
        }
    }

}
```

and also simple receiver

```java
@Component
public class VirtualTopicReceiver {

    @JmsListener(destination="Consumer.myConsumer0.VirtualTopic.TEST-VIRTUAL-TOPIC", containerFactory = "defaultMessageListenerContainerFactory")
    public void receiveMessages(Session session, String message) {
        System.out.println(message);
        try {
            session.commit();
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            System.out.println(session.getTransacted());
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

both are springboot's.

What I am doing is:

- starting receiver app in terminal
- starting publisher app in terminal
- seeing some output from receiver and killing it with ctrl+c
- starting receiver again

now I'm missing output from 10 seconds, also netstat is showing for 10 seconds that connection is established

```
$ netstat -an | grep 575* | grep 61616
  TCP    127.0.0.1:57809        127.0.0.1:61616        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:61616        127.0.0.1:57788        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:61616        127.0.0.1:57789        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:61616        127.0.0.1:57790        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:61616        127.0.0.1:57791        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:61616        127.0.0.1:57792        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:61616        127.0.0.1:57793        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:61616        127.0.0.1:57794        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:61616        127.0.0.1:57795        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:61616        127.0.0.1:57796        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:61616        127.0.0.1:57797        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:61616        127.0.0.1:57798        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:61616        127.0.0.1:57799        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:61616        127.0.0.1:57800        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:61616        127.0.0.1:57801        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:61616        127.0.0.1:57802        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:61616        127.0.0.1:57803        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:61616        127.0.0.1:57804        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:61616        127.0.0.1:57805        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:61616        127.0.0.1:57806        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:61616        127.0.0.1:57808        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:61616        127.0.0.1:57809        ESTABLISHED
```

do you know how to get rid of that 10 seconds delay? If I'll make some application with multiple instances of receivers I can't risk losing messages for 10 seconds before ActiveMQ will switch instances, but for now I have no idea how to fix that.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, everything is clear now. Yesterday I've spent whole day reading documentation and trying to understand this behaviour, but today I decided to make sure that consumer is really dying when pressing ctrl+c - well it doesn't.

I've created simple rest endpoint in another application that my receiver was calling and after ctrl+c receiver still makes rest calls for 10 seconds.

Presented in question behaviour is present in git bash.